# Dynamic required validation for different buttons?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I'm currently learning about jsf 2.0 from core jsf 2.0 book + glassfish + cdi.

I have a question about the validation feature of JSF.

Let's say i have a very simple login application, which has a very simple layout like :

userid : (input field for userid - using required="true")
password : (input secret for password - using required="true")
loginButton + registerButton(using immediate="true") + checkUserIdAvailabilityButton

Now, let's say the loginButton is pressed, and the userid and password are left empty, validation error would occur on both of the fields, and that's working as what i intended.

And when the registerButton is pressed, it doesnt care whether the userid or password is filled by the user, since it's using immediate="true", thus bypassing validation and the command gets executed at the apply request value phase, and that's still working as what i intended.

And here comes my problem .. When the checkUserIdAvailabilityButton is pressed, i only expect the userid to be filled, and i dont need to care about whether the password field is filled or not, but the password field will throw error saying that it's a required field.

Is there anyway to resolve this kind of problem ? I know this could be a very simple application, but in my working place, i think they design lots of screens like this, like the save button along with refresh button with different required fields but the buttons are in the same page.

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set both the availability button and username field with `immediate="true"` **and** put the register button in a *separate* `<h:form>`.

E.g.

```
<h:form>
     <h:inputText value="#{bean.username}" required="true" immediate="true" />
     <h:inputSecret value="#{bean.password}" required="true" />
     <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{bean.login}" />
     <h:commandButton value="Check name availability" action="#{bean.checkNameAvailability}" immediate="true" />
</h:form>
<h:form>
     <h:commandButton value="Register" action="#{bean.register}" />
</h:form>
```

An alternative is to determine in the required attribute which button is been pressed (it's then present as request parameter).

```
<h:form id="form">
     <h:inputText value="#{bean.username}" required="#{not empty param['form:login'] or not empty param['form:check']}" />
     <h:inputSecret value="#{bean.password}" required="#{not empty param['form:login']}" />
     <h:commandButton id="login" value="Login" action="#{bean.login}" />
     <h:commandButton id="check" value="Check name availability" action="#{bean.checkNameAvailability}" />
     <h:commandButton value="Register" action="#{bean.register}" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. I understand the second solution. But could you explain about the first solution ? about the immediate="true" on the bean.username field, because so far i only understand the effect of immediate="true" on the command buttons, which is to bypassing validation and the command gets executed at the apply request value phase

Comment: A submit by a button with `immediate="true"` will only process fields which also have `immediate="true"`. The `immediate` attribute is explained in more detail by practical examples in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html). Note: the article's code is targeted on JSF 1.2, but will work on 2.0 as well and the theory applies as good on JSF 2.0.