# How to make an element conditionally required in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a simple input text element in my form.

The user has 2 possible actions to take on that form: 1) approve the form and 2) reject the form. So there are 2 buttons at the bottom of the form for the user to click on.

If the user clicks on `approve` the `comment` inputField should be optional. If the user clicks on `reject` the `comment` inputField should be required.

Here is a simple representation of the form:

```
<h:form>
    <p:inputText id="comment" required="???" .../>

    <p:commandButton id="approve" ... />
    <p:commandButton id="reject" ... />
</h:form>
```

Comment: Thank you @BalusC! I guess I was not using the correct search words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
<h:form id="forma">
    <p:inputText id="comment" 
                 value="#{userView.firstname}" 
                 title="comment" 
                 required="#{not empty param[reject.clientId]}"/>
    <p:message for="comment"/>

    <p:commandButton id="approve" 
                     binding="#{approve}" 
                     value="approve" 
                     process="@form" 
                     update="@form"/>
    <p:commandButton id="reject" 
                     binding="#{reject}" 
                     value="reject" 
                     process="@form" 
                     update="@form"/>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question looks similar to [Dynamic required validation for different buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193264/dynamic-required-validation-for-different-buttons).

Modify the `required` attribute as follows:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:inputText id="comment" required="#{not empty param['form:reject']}" ... />
    <p:commandButton id="approve" ... />
    <p:commandButton id="reject" ... />
</h:form>
```